# passing associated object in json.array jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have list of appointments in **@appointments**.
I can access corresponding customer of an appointment like this

```
appointment_object.customer
```

Now I want to render customer partial file
which accepts customer object.

This is jbuilder file which renders partial of customer. Problem here is I have 
@appointments but I want to send corresponding customer inside this partial.(I dont 
to change customer partial as I know we can do it inside it also.But this is commong partial
and I dont to want to change it)

```
json.customers do
  json.array! @appointments, partial: 'api/v1/customers/customer', as: :customer
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found solution myself**

```
json.customers do
  json.array! @appointments do | app |
    json.partial! 'api/v1/customers/customer', customer: app.customer
  end
end
```